# Appcelerator Studio error : [ERROR] : Failed to package application

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am brand new to the app development arena, and I downloaded and installed Appcelerator Studio to help me learn more.

I tried compiling and running Appcelerator's example of their first app, (FaveBooks).  But it completely fails to run in the Android emulator throwing the following error:
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1

I can provide the code if needed, but it is directly from this link:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App-section-37541502_CreatingYourFirstTitaniumApp-Createanewproject

[Appcelerator example of first app](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App-section-37541502_CreatingYourFirstTitaniumApp-Createanewproject)

Multiple Inet searches have failed to turn up an answer.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please confirm the following things like Studio Version, SDK Version, Android SDK Version, Build-Tools Version. Unless we get these details, we will not be above to provide the right help.

Comment: My apologies:  Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.0.0  ; Android SDK tools 24.3; Android SDK Platform tools 22; Android build tools 22.0.1

Comment: Can you try to download Build tools 20, manually remove the build tools 22.0.1 folder and then try to clean build your application? Do let us know the result of it.

Comment: Soumya - do you have a link to the Build tools 20?  I cannot find a mirror source anywhere that has it.  Thank you!

Comment: Launch Android SDK Manager and you can find it in under build - tools. It willbe present there. Can you please check and confirm.

Comment: Soumya, let me check on that and see if I can get it installed.  Do you know where the 22.0.1 build tools folder is located?

Comment: It should be present inside the build-tools folder on the android sdk folder. For me it is in C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools. It might be different for you, but it will be present inside build-tools. Ensure that you have only the folder named 20.0.0. If you have any folder name higher than 20.0.0, then remove and move them to trash.

Comment: That did not work.  I am still getting the original error message.  Any other thoughts?   Thank you

Comment: Ok. No issues. Can you tell me the Android version in which you are trying to deploy it? Also can you see if python is installed on your machine. The recent version of python should be good.

Comment: Python 2.7 is installed.  The version of Android I am trying to run is Android 4.x

Comment: If you create a new project, with no codes, just the default generated code. Is this project getting built and is it working or it is also generating the same error?

Comment: Can you try to download the GA SDK once again and try it. For one of my colleague also faced the same issue and he resolved it by downloading the Appcelerator SDK once again, clean. Can you try this.

Comment: Hi Soumya,  Thank you for the idea.  I am all but giving up on Appcelerator.  I cannot figure out why, just compiling something as simple as "Hello World" cannot be performed with this platform.  It honestly should not be this hard to get it up and running.  So I think I am going to scrap it.